# Question about LI functions (with module)

Tags: linear-algebra

I have two functions: f(x) = 2x and g(x) = |x|

The questions asks to show these functions are Linearly Dependent in the interval ]-2,0[ and LI in the interval ]-2,2[.

I solved some exercises about this but none of them had module, and I couldn't find *any* solved examples with modules.

Answer (score 1):

In $]-2,0[$ it's clear that $g(x)=-x$ so in this interval you have that $f(x)+2g(x)=0$ for all values of $x$, thus they are linearly dependent in $]-2,0[.

In $]-2,2[$, let's say that $$af(x)+bg(x)=0$$ if $x=1$, the equation is $$2a+b=0$$ and for $x=-1$ you have $$-2a+b=0$$ Then the only solution is $a=b=0$ so $f$ and $g$ are linearly independent in $]-2,2[$.